# Trim on "Rewrite Results" doesn't work as expected

Tags: views

In my website I have a view showing event names. They are set to trim on 47 letters, "Add an ellipsis " and "Trim only on a word boundary".

However, an event called

"XXX Concorso di composizione e arrangiamento per Orchestra jazz" going on three lines.

I tried different settings (I mean enable/disable the three options mentionted) but still I don't understand why the word "composizione" is going on a new line.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please try to rewrite your problem (with a simple screenshot maybe) without us needing to click a load more button 10 times on an external site. Please remove the link to your site. Please add information about what "I tried different settings" settings you actually tried already. Thanks!

Comment: I added the website to see the concrete problem giving possibility to access to inspect element. I know it's boring click 10 times, but the problem is only on that view :(

Comment: A link to the page showing the issue doesn't replace an exhaustive description of what happens. If I can only understand what the problem is by accessing the site, chances are that the question is too broad.

Comment: Then, a question should be fully understandable from future users too. If they need to look at a site that is changed since the question was asked, or doesn't exist anymore, they will not understand the question nor the answers.

Comment: Ok I understand...maybe both options together (web + pic )are the best :)

Comment: External links to your own site/product should actually be considered as spam. Maybe it's just a fake question aiming to gain some traffic and/or SEO juice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a monospace font, so trimming based on a certain number of characters will not guarantee that your text will not wrap. Think about this example: The string "WWWWW" will wrap when "lllll" may not because "W"s are wider than "l"s.

You should be handling this via CSS. You can either use a monospace font (all letters are the same width) and you can then rely on character count (just remember that people can individualize the font size in their browser so for those people you might be out of luck with this method) or you can use a overflow hidden to make sure that text doesn't appear to wrap to the third line. Something like:

```
.classname {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-height: 3.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You're correct, but "phisically", the word "composizione" could easily stay on the first line without going on the next line! I corrected the problem using font-size: 22px, but still I don't well understand why some word goes on new line even if there's all the space for it..

Comment: That's not an issue with views, but with your container widths, CSS, the available space (paddings/margins) and the word wrapping settings. Consider additionally adding `&shy;` word break indicators to your event names that allow the browsers to break long words.